# 'Module not found' when importing a library service in the same workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created an Angular workspace that contains an application and a library, as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries). The library contains a service that is exported in `public-api.ts`.

The problem is that I cannot import the library services in the application. I get

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lib-name/services/utils.service' 
>   in 'component-that-uses-the-service.ts'

Where `lib-name` is the library created in the workspace.

The application does not throw any errors in Visual Studio Code, and the library module is imported in the component that uses it.

When I run the application with `ng serve` I get the error message.

According to the Angular team:

```
When you build your own library, it has to find the mapping in your tsconfig paths.
```

The tsconfig paths seem OK, they were configured when I created the library with `ng generate library` (the tsconfig file resides in the root of the workspace).

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you build the library and install it in your workspace?  `ng build my-lib  && npm install dist/my-lib`

Comment: @JasonWhite I don't want to use npm, shouldn't the library be imported without npm if both the library and the application reside in the same workspace?

Comment: I haven't worked too much with libraries in Angular, but when I've fiddled around with them I've always had to build the library which is outputted to `<workspace>/dist/<library-name>` then had to use npm to install it into the project I wanted to use the library in.

Comment: This might be a helpful read. https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-7-series-part-2-create-custom-library-8d7a0494b2cc

Comment: @JasonWhite The problem happens only with services, components are imported OK

Comment: Did you put the service in the `providers` of the library `@Module()`?

Comment: you have to import your service like this: ``import {  YourService } from 'lib-name' ``

Comment: @JasonWhite I put the service class name in `providers` it didn't help

Comment: @AbolfazlR  that was exactly the problem, thanks!!!

Comment: @ps0604  I sent the comment as an answer to be more useful

Comment: Hi, just an additional note: angular workspaces aren't ideal in setting up a monorepo. You cannot have an application which references services from a library that in its turn references services from another library. To solve this, you could use [NX](https://nx.dev). However I've experienced that once in a while they tend to forget that some developers are using Windows, which splits command line arguments by spaces, instead of double-dashes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to import your service with the complete path.

you have to import your service like this

```
import { YourService } from 'lib-name'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've covered all your bases with exporting the right members and have your angular.json configured properly try updating your root `tsconfig.json`

my issue was that `compilerOptions` didnt have the right path.

e.g.

```
{
compilerOptions: {
   paths: {
   "your-library": ["dist/your-library", "dist/your-library/your-library"]
   }
}}
```